# how to obtain values from xml tag and save in text file with new line at the end of the text file and also number of counts

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
   private void button33_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {  

      DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)

        {

            DialogResult result2 = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)

            {

                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(openFileDialog1.FileName,

                folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

                MessageBox.Show("ZIP file extracted successfully!");

            }

        }

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files 

       (*.*)|*.*";

        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = 

        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)

        {

            XNamespace xns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

            XDocument xdInput = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);

            XElement xeDocument = xdInput.Root.Element(xns + "Document");

            XElement xePlaceMark = xeDocument.Element(xns + "Placemark");

            XElement xeCoord = xePlaceMark.Descendants(xns + 

            "coordinates").First();

            string[] lines = xeCoord.Value.Trim().Split(new string[] { ",0 "

            }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

           File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\New folder\longlat.txt", lines);

                    }
```

in this code it extract the xml filesand save the vales from

```
<coordinates>
80.41501791166907,15.31966921785412,80.66681262872422,15.30770770315245,81.04469571795477,15.27884283211159,0 
</coordinates>
```

these tags and save it in longlat text file. like this it saves for other coordinates from other document ,and my final output got looks like

```
80.41501791166907,15.31966921785412
80.66681262872422,15.30770770315245
81.04469571795477,15.27884283211159,0
81.03730709247927,15.27205299521836
80.99634866995486,14.75503556947802,0
```

the first 3 is 1 set and next 2 is second set etc...

what i need to do count the no of lines in first set and write on top of first set ,again count the the second set of lines write on top of second set ,and then it should continue for entire set of coordinates tag extracted.

o/p i need to obtain is in this manner

```
3 0

80.41501791166907,15.31966921785412
80.66681262872422,15.30770770315245
81.04469571795477,15.27884283211159

2 0

81.03730709247927,15.27205299521836
80.99634866995486,14.75503556947802
```

etc....

3- number of line along with space and 0 . Can you guys help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need two `Splits`, one with `",0"` and followed one with `","`.

```
var lines = xeCoord.Value.Trim()
    .Split(new string[] {",0"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x=> 
        {   
            int i=0;
            var splits = x.Split(new string[] {","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)       
                .GroupBy(g=> i++/2)                       //Group for consecutive values to form a coordinate.
                .Select(s=>string.Join(",",s))            // Join them
                .ToList();                  
            splits.Insert(0,splits.Count().ToString());   // Insert the count at the beginning
            return splits;

        })
        .SelectMany(x=>x);                                // flatten the structure

 // now write these lines to file.
 File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\New folder\longlat.txt", lines);
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Of8b7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            string input = "<coordinates>80.41501791166907,15.31966921785412,80.66681262872422,15.30770770315245,81.04469571795477,15.27884283211159,0 </coordinates>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            string[] groups = ((string)doc.Element("coordinates")).Trim().Split(new string[] {",0"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Boolean first = true;
            foreach (string group in groups)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }

                string[] coordinates = group.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}", coordinates.Length / 2, 0);
                writer.WriteLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count() - 1; i += 2)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("{0},{1}", coordinates[i], coordinates[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
}
```